# Legend for colors used by the EMMA Code Coverage Report

Tags: java, unit-testing, emma

Where can I find a legend for the default colors used by Emma for highlighting source code when a HTML coverage report is generated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Annotations](http://www.eclemma.org/userdoc/annotations.html)

green for fully covered lines,
yellow for partly covered lines and
red for lines that have not been executed at all.